# Compiling C++ Program with libcurl Dependencies: Missing DLLs Despite Static Linking

Tags: c++, compilation, mingw, libcurl

i have written a cpp program that when it scrapes some text from a site and gets some info from the windows OS, it sends the information via telegram.

The code uses this dependecies:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <map>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
```

I use Sublime text and Mingw64 from MSYS2.

I use mingw for compiling at the begging it worked, but when i tried on another machine it gave a lot missing dlls. I managed to resolve a lot of them by using this command:
`$ g++ .\keg.cpp my.res -lcurl -Wdeprecated-declarations -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -mwindows -o "test.exe"`

With this command it only gave 2 missing dlls : "libcurl-4.dll", "libwinpthread-1.dll"

I also tried to add the dll files in the same folder, but then it gives more missing dlls.

Does someone know how to resolve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `-lcurl` should link with the static `libcurl.a`, but you don't seem to use MSYS2 `packman`.

Comment: you copy them one by one until all the errors go away, this is why using a virtual machine or microsoft's sandbox feature in windows is good for testing your software before you send it to anyone else.

Comment: they are too many and i want it all in one executable

Comment: @GiovanniFittizio then you can follow `273K` answer of static linking libraries, at least all mingw `g++` internal libraries can be linked with `-static` flag at the end of the command line, for the other libraries you need to consult their documentation on how to link them statically.

Comment: libcurl has dependencies. You need to find static libraries for libcurl and all of the dependencies, and add them to your command line. Same is presumably true for libwinpthread but don't quote me on that.